# Exercise 18b in Schutz's First course in GR

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, linear-algebra

The question is as follows:

> Show that a timelike vector and a non-zero null vector cannot be orthogonal.

So we have a timelike vector $\vec{A}$, s.t $\vec{A}^2<0$; and a non-zero null vector, $\vec{B}$ s.t $\vec{B}^2=0$.

So we get that $\vec{A}\cdot \vec{B} = \frac{(\vec{A}+\vec{B})^2-\vec{A}^2}{2}$.

I need to show that $\vec{A}\cdot \vec{B} \ne 0$, if it were otherwise then:
$$(\vec{A}+\vec{B})^2 = \vec{A}^2$$
How to continues from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\vec{A}$ is timelike then we can find an inertial frame in which:

$$ \vec{A} = (a, 0, 0, 0) $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: OK, then we have $\vec{A}^2 =-a^2<0$ and $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B} = -aB^0$, and this is zero only when $B^0=0$ in which case $\vec{B}=\vec{0}$.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: typo? Did you mean $\vec{B}^2 \gt 0$ i.e. $\vec{B}$ is spacelike not null?

Comment: Well, $\vec{B}$ is a null vector so we have $\vec{B}^2=0$. Now, if $B^0=0$ then we have: $(B^1)^2+(B^2)^2+(B^3)^2=0$ which means that $\vec{B} = \vec{0}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: Oh I see, you're arguing that any null vector normal to $A$ must be zero. I would say instead that to be normal to $A$ any (non-zero) vector $B$ must have the form $(0, b_1, b_2, b_3)$ and therefore must be spacelike not null. But either approach is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is tempting to generalize OP's question to the following proposition.

> *Proposition.* Given an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$ with (possibly degenerate) indefinite [sesquilinear form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) $\beta:V\times V \to \mathbb{F}$ of [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia) $(n_+,n_0,n_-)$, with  $n_+ + n_0 + n_-=n$, where it is assumed that $$n_-~=~1.$$ Then 
>   $$ \forall x,y~\in~ V :\quad \beta(x,x)~\leq~0\quad \wedge\quad \beta(y,y)~\leq~0\quad \wedge\quad \beta(x,y)~=~0$$ 
>   $$\quad \Rightarrow\quad  \beta(x,x)~=~0~=~\beta(y,y)\quad\vee\quad x~\in~V^{\perp}\quad\vee\quad y~\in~V^{\perp}. $$

In the non-degenerate case, the proposition states that *two non-zero, mutually orthogonal, non-spacelike vectors are both lightlike.*

*Sketched proof:*

1. Pick an arbitrary (but fixed) positive definite, sesquilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: V\times V \to \mathbb{F}$.
2. Find the unique Hermitian linear operator $B:V\to V$ such that 
   $$\forall x,y~\in~ V:\quad\beta( x, y )~=~\langle x, By \rangle.$$
3. Decompose the vector space $$V~=~V_+\oplus V_0 \oplus V_-$$ in eigenspaces for $B$, which are mutually orthogonal wrt. $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Here $V_0=V^{\perp}$ and
   $$n_+ ~=~\dim V_+,\quad n_0 ~=~\dim V_0,\quad n_- ~=~\dim V_-~=~1.$$
4. Note that, in a hopefully obvious notation,
   $$\beta(x,y)~=~\beta(x_+,y_+)+\beta(x_-,y_-),$$
   etc.
5. Assume that $x,y\notin V^{\perp}$. From assumptions, we get that
   $$ 0~\leq~\beta( x_+, x_+)~\leq~ -\beta( x_-, x_-)~>~0,$$ 
   $$ 0~\leq~\beta( y_+, y_+)~\leq~ -\beta( y_-, y_-)~>~0, $$ 
   $$ 0~\leq~\beta( x_+, y_+)~=~ -\beta( x_-, y_-). $$
6. From [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) for a positive definite sesquilinear form, we get that 
   $$|\beta( x_+, y_+ )|^2~\leq~\beta( x_+, x_+)\beta( y_+, y_+)$$
   and
   $$ \beta( x_-, x_-)\beta( y_-, y_-) ~=~|\beta( x_-, y_- )|^2.$$
   The latter since $ x_- \parallel y_- $.
7. Combine the above to conclude that 
   $$ \beta( x_+, x_+)~=~ -\beta( x_-, x_-)$$ 
   and
   $$ \beta( y_+, y_+)~=~ -\beta( y_-, y_-). $$